# Android ActionBar on Lollipop not styling correctly

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-styles

I am designing an app with [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design), but I am having trouble styling the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

First of all, I can not get the ActionBar to render a shadow.  I have tried setting the elevation in multiple ways:

*In the [styles.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) (v21)*:

```xml
<item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
<item name="elevation">4dp</item>
```

*In the [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method*

```java
getActionBar().setElevation(4);
```

However, none of these result in the ActionBar rendering a shadow.  Not sure if this is important, but I am running [Android 5.0.1 Lollipop](https://www.android.com/intl/en_us/versions/lollipop-5-0/).  What am I missing in trying to render a shadow?  I don't really want to make a drawable shadow and set it as the window background.

---

Secondly, my ActionBar [buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) are square, and when I click on them, the ripple is cut off in a square, while in other apps I have used the mask for the ripples has been circular, and my app had been using round buttons, but recently it changed and I don't know why.  Could I have accidentaly changed something making them square?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that u use ActionBar while the other apps use [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Read about and change your code, everything should work after that.

Comment: Ahh yes, I guess I didn't do enough research on material design... Thank you!